# Can you use Filestream in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, sqlfilestream

There is a way to use this feature in EF

Comment: Thank you for that information. What is your question? And what is your specific problem/task at hand?

Comment: I want to save the files through SQL
Because I have a lot of files with high volume